# Relationship query

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to write the relationship query and how to fetch the record from the query on visualforce page.
For ex- i have one account object and one contact object then how to write the relationship from parent to child and child to parent because when i am using the query it will give only id

```
Account con;
con = [select account.name,(Select contact.firstName,contact.lastName from account.contacts) from account limit 1];
system.debug(con);
```

how to fetch the value of contact.lastName and same when i use child to parent ?????
And then how to to display it on visualforce page.

Please explain me

Comment: Do you have only one single Child contact below Account?

Comment: go thru this article.. it covers the relationship queries in detail -  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: Why is a variable of type Account defined with a name `con` implying it is a Contact? This is not good practice. The variable should be named something like `acct` or perhaps `acctWRelatedContacts`. Also prefixing `account.` and `contact.` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

###### Child To Parent Relationship :

In the child-to-parent Relationship, we can query on Contact and retrieve the values from Account that is associated.

Ex:

```
Contact C = [Select First Name, LastName, Account.Name, Account.Industry from Contact where id = 'XXXXX'];
```

---

###### Parent To Child Relationship :

In the parent-to-child relationship. We can query on the parent object and we will get the details about child records.

```
Account a = [Select Name, (Select Contact.FirstName, contact.LastName from Account. Contacts) From Account where id ='xxxxxxx'];
```